# Hiding Grub Menu (Grub 2.02 / Ubuntu 18.10)

Tags: grub, boot-loader

I have troubles "deactivating" the Grub boot loader.

Basically I just want to hide it to spare me some time.

Therefore I tried editing the `grub` file in `/etc/default` and changed the values according to [this page](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/ubuntu-1404-hide-grub-menu/) (or any other page referring to that matter).

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

At the end I also ran `sudo grub-update`.

Furthermore I tried reinstalling `grub` (`-pc`/`-common`) completely using `apt`.

I'm only running Ubuntu so either hiding it or instantly choosing the first option (without it showing) are viable. (`GRUB_DEFAULT` is already set to `0`).

Current behavior: Grub is not hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line into `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

From [Grub2/Setup in Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#line-234)  specific entries, item #16.2:

> While both methods prevent os-prober from running and placing items in the menu display, using this setting allows the 30_os-prober script, but not the os-prober command, to run. **This script enables the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT setting** and/or the ability to display a hidden menu by pressing the ESC key (depending on other settings). This functionality is lost if the 30_os-prober script is disabled by making it unexecutable.

However it makes any other OS disappear from the list. Memtest and advanced options will be still available.

Another option is to set `GRUB_TIMEOUT="1"`
While it is kind of a hack, it speeds boot up by 9 seconds and allows you to boot other systems.

Also remember to run `sudo update-grub` to apply any changes you made.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but sadly it didn't work. (both)